# JWT authentication system login through API

Tags: java, security, authentication, spring

This is my first time writing an authentication system. Here's how it works, first client needs to send credential within authorization header like { Authorization : 'Basic ' + credential } through API. I encoded the credential with base64 encoder ('username:password') and then if the authentication is successfully it will return a jwt token within response headers like { Authorization : 'Bearer ' + jwtToken }. Is there any insecurity with this implementation that I should concern?
Here's my code

Security configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
        @Autowired
        private AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private AccountService accountService;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // Mock an account for testing purpose
            this.accountService.saveAccount(new Account("pink", passwordEncoder().encode("1234"), 10L));
            auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.cors();
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/auth").permitAll().
                            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                            exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }
    }
```

UserDetailsService implementation:

```
    @Service
    public class AccountDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
        @Autowired
        private AccountRepository accountRepository;
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            Account account = accountRepository.findByUserName(username);
            if (account == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
            }
            return new AccountPrincipal(account);
        }
    }
```

Custom filter for jwt:

```
    @Component
    public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        @Autowired
        private AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            String username = null;
            String jwt = null;

            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
                System.out.println(jwt);
                username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
            }

            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

                UserDetails accountDetails = this.accountDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, accountDetails)) {

                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            accountDetails, null, accountDetails.getAuthorities());
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                            .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                }
            }

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
```

Jwt object for creating and validating jwt :

```
    @Service
    public class JwtUtil {

        private Key SECRET_KEY = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);
        public String extractUsername(String token) {
            return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
        }

        public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
            return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
        }
        public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
            final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
            return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
        }
        private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
            return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        }

        private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
            return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
        }

        public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
            Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
            return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
        }

        private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

            return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 10)))
                    .signWith(SECRET_KEY).compact();

        }
        public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
            final String username = extractUsername(token);
            return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
        }
    }
```

Controller for authentication

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
    public class AuthenticationController {
        @Autowired
        private AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        @Autowired
        private JwtUtil jwtTokenUtil;
        @RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<?> getAuthenticate(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization) throws Exception{
            String encodedCredentials = authorization.substring(6);
            byte[] decodedCredentialByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedCredentials);
            String[] decodedCredentialString = new String(decodedCredentialByte).split(":");
            System.out.println(decodedCredentialString[0] + ":" + decodedCredentialString[1]);
            try {
                authenticationManager.authenticate(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(decodedCredentialString[0], decodedCredentialString[1])
                );
            }
            catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
                throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
            }

            final UserDetails userDetails = this.accountDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(decodedCredentialString[0]);
            final String jwt = "Bearer " + jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, jwt);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(headers ,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

Account entity and account principal:

````
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Account")
    public class Account {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long accountId;
        private String userName;
        private String passWord;
        private Long nuggerPoint;

        public Account(){

        }
        public Account(String username, String password, Long nuggerpoint){
            this.userName = username;
            this.passWord = password;
            this.nuggerPoint = nuggerPoint;
        }
        public Long getAccountId(){
            return accountId;
        }
        public void setAccountId(Long accountId){
            this.accountId = accountId;
        }
        public String getUserName(){
            return this.userName;
        }
        public void setUserName(String userName){
            this.userName = userName;
        }
        public String getPassword(){
            return this.passWord;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password){
            this.passWord = password;
        }
        public Long getNuggerPoint(){
            return this.nuggerPoint;
        }
        public void setNuggerPoint(Long nuggerPoint){
            this.nuggerPoint = nuggerPoint;
        }
    }
    public class AccountPrincipal implements UserDetails {
        private Account account;
        public AccountPrincipal(Account account) {
            this.account = account;
        }
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.account.getPassword();
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return this.account.getUserName();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```
````